RPi Zero W not connecting to WiFi with WPA3/WPA2 compatibility mode nor with 802.11w (MFP)
I got a new home routers that supports openwrt so I got openwrt installed and programs my WLANs. My previous router didn't support 802.11ax (WiFi6) but this new one does.
So, on this new router I configured my 2.4GHz WLAN to support compatibility mode for WPA2/WPA3. However, my RPi ZeroW couldn't connect until I configured only WPA2 and fully disable management frame protection (I tried Raspberry Pi 3 also with same issue).
Either WPA3 (compatibility mode) or MFP (mandatory or optional) doesn't make my connection working on raspberry pi.
Obviously, the old wifi chipset on my pi doesn't like new router's capability that it doesn't really understand.
But my question is: shouldn't it work fine with compatibility mode?
I assume in compatibility mode while both wpa3/2 are allowed and MFP is optional that my pi shall connect coz it will connect with wpa2 and will not use MFP as it is optional. But it doesn't seem to be the case.
Anyone may have noticed same issue? is there a solution or a driver's update? I don't think this is a HW issue as my router shall be backward compatible with old clients!!

I’m voting to close this question because it's about wifi networking - NOT Raspberry Pi. There are other SE sites that support networking (Unix&Linux SE for example).

You have a point. But I posted it here coz it is more related to Raspberry Pi chip itself that seems lack support of mentioned features and I actually wanted advise from Raspberry Pi users about this from their experience.
